# Сервис с парсингом HTML страниц

Tags: c#, парсер

Приветствую!

У меня написан простой парсер сайта на C#. Алгоритм выполнения примерно такой - запускаю  exe файл -> он анализирует содержимое HTML страниц -> сохраняет результат в БД на удаленном сервере. Все работает хорошо, но есть одна проблема - каждый раз нужно запускать парсер в ручную. Можно ли с помощью asp или другой .Net технологии создать сервис который выполнял бы работу парсера автоматически, например раз в 1 час ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Планировщик заданий**

Вы можете использовать планировщик заданий для запуска приложения по расписанию, нажимаем *"Win + R"* и набираем *"taskschd.msc"*, настраиваете необходимые параметры.
[Ссылка.](http://the-komp.ru/planirovshhik-zadanij-windows-7.html)

**Консольное приложение работающее всё время**

Ну и есть ещё другой способ, можно просто написать консольное приложение, которое будут бездействовать всё необходимое время, и в определённое время запускать необходимое задание. В этом случае консольное приложение необходимо что бы было запущено всё время. Так же можно его [запустить как сервис](https://windowsnotes.ru/programs/kak-zapustit-prilozhenie-v-vide-sluzhby-windows/).

Для вызова функции в определённое время (по расписанию), в случае консольного приложения, можно использовать например [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/). Эта библиотека на C# позволяет запускать любые функции в заданное время либо по расписанию.

Пример синтаксиса:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("some-id", () => Console.WriteLine(), Cron.Hourly);
```

запускает каждый час `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Какой смысл? Но тогда мне придется держать свой ПК постоянно включенным .

Comment: @Сергей ну а как вы хотите что бы у вас выполнялось задание регулярно при выключенным ПК?

Comment: @Сергей HangFire  если процессы был выключен запустит все таски которые пропустил при включении процесса. То есть если вы включите компьютер, то таски запланированные, например на ночь сработают. Возможно для этого нужны специальные настройки, для ASP.NET работает по умолчанию.

Comment: @Сергей кроме того вы можете запустить ваш процесс на сервере/хостинге.

Comment: Про сервер я как раз и думал. Тогда мне нужен ASP проект?

Comment: @Сергей про сервер всё тоже остаётся что я написал, просто это надо сделать на сервере.

Comment: @Сергей если у вас VDS или ваш личный сервер, то то что я описал сделать будет не проблема. Если у вас shared hosting то там уже по ситуации, может быть доступ через админку к планировщику, а может вообще без возможности, тут надо по ситуации смотреть. Если shared hosting то лучше просто спросить у техподдержки как сделать запуск по расписанию, если вообще возможно. Высока вероятность что сделать это можно, так как это распространённая задача.

Comment: Что бы запустить exe по планировщику нужен же виндовый хостинг ?

Comment: @Сергей Да Windows хостинг с возможностью запуска по расписанию. Либо VDS на Windows.